# Is there a constant term in the quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

A quadratic equation: $ax^2 + bx + c$ has $c$ as a constant term.
I've notice a quadratic form: $x^\mathrm T Dx + b^\mathrm T x$, has no such thing?

I'm trying to maximize a profit function of the form:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Profit}
=& \big((d_{11} \mathrm{Price}_1 + c_{11}) + (d_{21} \mathrm{Price}_2 + c_{21})\big)  (\mathrm{Price}_1 - \mathrm{Cost}_1) \\
&+
\big((d_{12} \mathrm{Price}_1 + c_{12}) + (d_{22} \mathrm{Price}_2 + c_{22})\big) (\mathrm{Price}_2 - \mathrm{Cost}_2)
\end{align}$$

All $d_{ij}$ and $c_{ij}$ are known, so are the Costs. Maximizing/Optimization is done on Price$_1$ and Price$_2$ (unknown).

After dissolving the brackets I will be left with a constant term, due to multiplying Cost with $c_{ij}$. So when trying to formulate the profit function in quadratic form, I don't know what to do with the absolute term. Does leaving it out make a difference?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Although leaving the constant term out will change the profit function, it will not change the $x$ at which profit is maximized.

Comment: Also, see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) for instructions on how to format mathematical expressions on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximizing $$x^TDx+b^Tx+f\tag{1}$$ is equivalent to maximizing $$x^TDx+b^Tx\tag{2}$$ since they are vertical translation of each other.

If you solver return you the solution that $x^*$ is the optimal solution and $g^*$ is the corresponding objective value for $(2)$, $x^*$ is the optimal solution to $(1)$ and $g^*+f$ is the corresponding objective value.